# Check if there was a redirection in Fish

Tags: linux, shell, fish

I'm writing a simple function for `fish-shell` that should behave like this :

```
theFunc someArguments
somecommand | theFunc
```

I looking for a way to know if the function was called with a *pipe* / *redirection* or not.
Do you have an idea SO?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally you get that information with [`isatty(stdout)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty)  Sorry, but I don't know what name that goes under in `fish-shell`.  BTW, are you interested only in redirection of the single function, or also calls made within a larger script, when the whole script's output has been redirected?

Comment: Yay, it works thanks! I'm only interested in the *left redirection* or the *piping* to the function ;)

Comment: Ahh, then test `stdin`.  It won't tell you whether that function is specifically piped vs the whole script, but maybe that's good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm setting the informations if anyone needs it.

As [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) pointed it out, we should use the `isatty` function.
For **fish-shell** you can simply check:

```
if isatty stdin
    # Your code here.
end
```